# Is the Arens's space actually sequential??

Tags: general-topology

The Arens's space is presented [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/a-note-about-the-arens-space/) (and in many questions on this web) as the canonical example of a sequential space that is not Frèchet(-Urysohn).

Let me recall how the space is constructed. We take as the total space $X=\mathbb Z^+\cup\{\ast\}\cup(\mathbb Z^+\times\mathbb Z^+)$, where $\{\ast\}$ denotes a point that is not an integer (I could wirte $\infty$ as in the link).  In the link, the topology is given by the fundamental system of neighbourhoods of each point:

- Points $(n,m)$ are isolated.
- For positive integers, neighbourhoods of a point $n$ are of the form $B_m(n)=\{n\}\cup\{(n,j),j\geq m\}$, for $m\in\mathbb Z^+$.
- For $\ast$, the neighbourhoods are obtain removing from $X$ finitely many $B_1(n)$ and then removing finitely many $(m,n)$ of the resulting set.

Now, let me explain my doubt. I focus on the point $\ast$. Notice that every neighbourhood of $\ast$ contains $\mathbb Z^+$. Hence, the closure $\bar{\{\ast\}}$ is the set $\mathbb Z^+\cup\{\ast\}$. Then the set $\{\ast\}$ is not closed. On the otehr hand, consider a sequence $\{x_n\}$ on $\{\ast\}$. Clearly, $x_n=\ast$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Moreover, the unique limit for this sequence is $\ast$. Hence $\{\ast\}$ is a sequentially closed set. If $X$ is sequential, then $\{\ast\}$ should also be closed.

I'm wrong, of course. But where is my mistake??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{\ast\}$ is certainly closed, Arens space is Hausdorff so $T_1$ in particular.
In fact it's easy to check that all points of the space unequal to $\ast$ have the property that all its basic neighbourhoods do not contain $\ast$ at all, making
$X \setminus \{\ast\}$ clearly open.

Every neighbourhood of $\ast$ intersects both $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+$, but does not contain that whole set, because we can omit points from it.

The sequential closure of $A = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is $A \cup \mathbb{Z}^+$ and the sequential closure of that subset is $X$. So the space is sequential (the closure is the iteration of the sequential closure) but not Fréchet-Urysohn (this means that closure = sequential closure right away). Your link shows an alternate way of showing sequentiality by writing $X$ as a quotient of a metric space.

Comment: I was removing only the columns, I was not considering the point $\{n\}$. Then my mistake. Thanks. Just one question: why the sequential closure of $A=\mathbb Z^+\times\mathbb Z^+$ is $A\cup\mathbb Z^+$? I mean, shouldn't the sequence $x_n=(n,m_0)$ converge to $\ast$?

Comment: @Dog_69 No, we can remove $(n,m_0)$ from **each** of the $B_1(n)$ in a neighbourhood of $\ast$. In the dantopology description it says "The neighborhoods at $\ast$ are obtained by removing from $X$ finitely many $B_{n,1}$ and by removing finitely many isolated points in each of the remaining $B_{n,1}$." I'm removing no $B_{n,1}$ and one point from each of $B_{n,1}$. A sequence that only has finitely many points in each "vertical" converges to no point of $X$.

Comment: @Dog_69 Removing whole $B_{n,1}$'s is needed to ensure that $((n_0,m))_m$ converges to $n_0$ but not to $\ast$, e.g.

Comment: Yes but it is not my sequence. My sequence is an infinite row $((n,m_0))_n$. So even if you remove finitely many $B_1(n)$ and finitely many isolated points, there should be a moment in which the sequence belong to each neighborhood of $\ast$.

Comment: @Dog_69 I know, I remove finitely many points from **each** vertical line, this gives me a neighbourhood of $\ast$ that contains no point of the sequence at all. I explained that earlier. You misunderstand the neighbourhoods of $\ast$.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. Now I get it.

Comment: Is it possible that the above open neighborhoods are also closed? Obviously $cl\{(n,m)\}=\{(n,m)\}$ But also it seems that $clB_m(n)=B_m(n)$. And finally, for each neighborhood $V_\ast$ of $\ast $ I can't find $n\in X\setminus V_\ast $ such that all its neighborhoods intersect $V_\ast$ so I would say that $V_\ast$ is closed.

Comment: @Dog_69 yes, I believe the basic neighbourhoods are clopen, giving an easy proof of tychonoffness. Why is that important?

Comment: No, it isn't important for my question. But I'm still studing the Arens' space and I found that result. I wanted to be sure. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dog_69 being countable and regular also makes Arens' space hereditarily (and even perfectly) normal. And first countable, and locally compact except at $\ast$. It really is quite minimally "bad". Just bad enough to be interesting...

Answer (score 2):

> Notice that every neighborhood of $*$ contains $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

For any $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $X\setminus B_1(n)$ is a neighborhood of $*$ with does not contain $n$.

> Hence, the closure $\overline{\{*\}}$ is the set $\mathbb{ℤ}^+\cup \{*\}$.

Even if your previous assertion were correct, this would not follow. The closure of $\{*\}$ is the intersection of all *closed* sets containing $*$. Equivalently, it is the set of all $x\in X$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains $*$. In fact, *no point* in $X$ other than $*$ has *any* basic open neighborhood which contains $*$. So $\{*\}$ is obviously closed.

Comment: As I told Henno, I was removing just the column of $B_m(n)$, not the point $\{n\}$, hence mi mistake. The ther mistake is also very big: for a point to be in the closure  of a set one needs every neighbourhood of THE POINT to meet the set, not the conevrse. I don't know what I was thinking this morning, sorry.